# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Angular->SpringBoot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm trying call the Angular2 a one Service the SpringBoot, but When I do call I get this error :

[image: error]

In my SpringBoot I have:

```
package com.service.configure;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.service")
public class ServiciosConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); 
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER");

    } 

}
```

In Angular2:

```
private fetchData() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/pg/get';
        this.service.fetchData(url).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log('mis datos ', data);
                this.headers = data[0].headers;
                this.params = data[1].params;
            });
    }
 public fetchData(url: string): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");
    return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
  }
```

If I put http://localhost:8080/pg/get I can get datas =).

But If I try with Angular is impossible...

My friend used "postman" and He recives datas

Code PostMan:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://myIp:8080/pg/get",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "e1225c81-8cb0-4809-9a2a-c82776793906"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});​
```

My controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value={"/pg"})
@CrossOrigin
public class PgController {

    @Autowired
    PgService pgRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    String home() {
        return "¡Servicio configuración!";
    }


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/get", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<tp_parametros_generales> getAllParameters() {
        List<tp_parametros_generales> tasks = pgRepository.getPg();
        return tasks;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-cors

Comment: try to use CORS Toggle chrome plugin, maybe it helps

Comment: I can't add extension for navigator "Chrome,firefox,etc" and I use Angular2 not AngularJs

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present

Answer (score 0):

For the develop you may to add:

```
@CrossOrigin()
```

annotation to your Controller's. It should work.

Comment: Hello, I have @CrossOrigin()

Comment: @EduBw h..this is wierd then.. You API url is correct ?

Comment: Yes, my friend  gets datas con http :// myIp :8080/pg/get", but with Angular not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@CrossOrigin` annotation on you Controller class or you can create an config file to enable `CrossOrigin`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using angular-cli's / webpack-dev-servers proxy support.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy

That way you can map angulars http://localhost:4200/pg to your spring boot server.
and since they now are on the same domain you won't get any cross domain problems.

Then when you go live, you use nginx proxy to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it

```
public class ServiciosConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors();
        }

        @Bean
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new
                    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
            return source;
        }

    }
```